# copying destination file which has soft link

Tags: linux, copy, symlink, file-copying

Issue description & issue is listed below.

```
cd D1/D2/ABC; ls
> file1.txt
> file2.txt -> /home/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/test_file.txt
```

Like ABC, there are sevral directories with same structure.

I would like to copy all these directories, with destination file which is linked.
(meaning, I want `/home/dir_A/dir_B/dir_C/test_file.txt` file to be copied instead of link)

in `/Z/123` directory, if I say `cp -rf /D1/D2/ABC` .
then, in `/z/123/` i would like to see-

> file1.txt
>
> test_file.txt

I tried with few options of cp, but no success, still trying..
How to sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question

```
cp -Lr source_dir destination_dir
```

From the man page:

```
   -L, --dereference
          always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```